# How to specify a Cron job for the following described Scenario?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Using Java & Quartz, is there a way to specify a Cron job (using a cron expression ***OR not***) for the following scenario;

```
(Parent-Event) ==> Start at <Time-X of day> & execute once every 5 days{

    (Child-Event) ==> Start at <Time-X of day> & execute 3-times at 1 hour intervals{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TriggerBuilder class has startAt and endAt method. startAt mekes start executing a job at specified date, whereas endAt makes stop executing a job at specified date.

Child-Event is scheduled by Parent-Event, and Time-X should be less than 22.

For Parent-Event:

- Cron expression: "0 0 X * * ?"
- startAt: *When you want to start a job*
- endAt  : *startAt date + 5 days*

For Child-Event:

- Cron expression: "0 0 X-X+2 * * ?"
- endAt  : *The midnight of the day when executing Parent-Event*